# Having trouble decoding JSON in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct, decoder

Here is the response JSON:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "title": "Top Albums",
    "id": "https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/apple-music/top-albums/all/25/explicit.json",
    "author": {
      "name": "iTunes Store",
      "uri": "http://wwww.apple.com/us/itunes/"
    },
    "links": [
      {
        "self": "https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/apple-music/top-albums/all/25/explicit.json"
      },
      {
        "alternate": "https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?genreId=34&popId=82&app=music"
      }
    ],
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2018 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.",
    "country": "us",
    "icon": "http://itunes.apple.com/favicon.ico",
    "updated": "2018-07-17T01:41:38.000-07:00",
    "results": [
      {
        "artistName": "Drake",
        "id": "1405365674",
        "releaseDate": "2018-06-29",
        "name": "Scorpion",
        "kind": "album",
        "copyright": "℗ 2018 Young Money/Cash Money Records",
        "artistId": "271256",
        "artistUrl": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/drake/271256?app=music",
        "artworkUrl100": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/5d/9b/97/5d9b97d6-9f78-e43b-7ba7-c2c42f53a166/00602567879121.rgb.jpg/200x200bb.png",
        "genres": [
          {
            "genreId": "18",
            "name": "Hip-Hop/Rap",
            "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/id18"
          },
          {
            "genreId": "34",
            "name": "Music",
            "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/id34"
          }
        ],
        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/scorpion/1405365674?app=music"
      },
      ...
```

And this is my code attempting to decode the above JSON:

```
struct object: Decodable {
    struct feed: Decodable {
        let title: String?
        let id: Int?


        struct Author: Decodable {
            let name: String?
            let uri: String?
        }

        let author: Author?
        struct Link: Decodable {
            let url: String?
            private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case url = "self"
            }
        }
        let links: [Link]?
        let copyright: String?
        let country: String?
        let icon: String?
        let updated: String?

        let results: [Album]?
    }
}

struct Album: Decodable {
    let artistName: String?
    let id: Int?
    let releaseDate: String?
    let name: String?
    let artworkUrl100: String?
    let kind: String?
    let copyright: String?
    let artistId: Int?
    let artistUrl: String?
    struct Genre: Decodable {
        let genreId: Int?
        let name: String?
        let url: String?
    }
    let genres: [Genre]?
    let url: String?
}
```

I am attempting to obtain the results with album name, artist name and image url. I am having difficulty understanding how to construct a suitable structure to obtain the data with a nested json.

When I attempt to obtain the data within my completion block, i just end up getting nil values for everything.

```
//Networking
let jsonString = "https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/apple-music/top-albums/all/25/explicit.json"

guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else { return }

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

    guard let data = data else { return }

    do {
        let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(object.feed.self, from: data)
        print(obj)
    } catch let jsonError {
        print("Error with json", jsonError)
    }

}.resume()
```

And my result is all nil:

`feed(title: nil, id: nil, author: nil, links: nil, copyright: nil, country: nil, icon: nil, updated: nil, results: nil)`

Comment: Never declare all struct members schematically as optionals. In case of an error you get `nil` values and you have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues.

Firstly, the outermost structure is an object under the key `feed`

You need:

```
struct object: Decodable {
    let feed: Feed
}

struct Feed: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let id: String

    let author: Author
    struct Link: Decodable {
        let url: String?
        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case url = "self"
        }
    }
    let links: [Link]
    let copyright: String
    let country: String
    let icon: String
    let updated: String

    let results: [Album]
}
```

and then you would decode it via:

```
do {
    let obj = try JSONDecoder().decode(object.self, from: data)
    print(obj)
} catch let jsonError {
    print("Error with json", jsonError)
}
```

Note that all of the "ids" are `String`s not `Int`s

Comment: Thank you so much @Paulw11, Just a question, why not use optionals for the struct members? For example, what if within Feed, the response had no author field?

Comment: If you don’t know if all of the fields will be present then, yes, you need optionals. If they will always be present then using optionals  is just annoying because you need to unwrap everything all the time. I guess it just depends on what the JSON will look like